# Changing an Office 365 group from Private to Public; from the Office 365 group admin itself VS from the sharepoint permsion setting popup

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups

In Office 365 groups we have 2 approaches (at-least 2 approaches) to change the group from private to public OR from public to private:

1. From SharePoint site >> site permission, as follow:-

[image]

2. From office 365 group admin, as follow:-

[image]

now i have noted in the first approach if we change the Group from Private to Public, the  SharePoint will add "Everyone except external" inside the SharePoint members group, while using the second approach this will not happen.. so is my assumption correct? and why we get this behavior, although we should be doing the same thing at the end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing, both of these settings will add "**Everyone except external**" group in the **Site Members**.

[image]

The only difference is that it can be implemented directly and quickly through **Site settings**(First one), while through the **O365 group**(Second one), you need to wait for a while and refresh the page.

It is recommended that you can reset it, and after waiting for a while, refresh and view the page again.

Comment: you are right,, it is a sync issue

Comment: Hi, John John. Thanks for your reply. Have a nice day!